# conversion between char * and const char *

Tags: c++, fltk

Fl_Widget have next constructor:

> Fl_Widget (int x, int y, int w, int h, const char *label=0L)

How can i send char* instead const char*? I just want use my char Tmp[255] variable in constructor.

Comment: Just sent it. A `const char*` parameter can receive a `char*`.

Comment: Did you try just sending it? `char*` (and hence `char[255]`) is convertible to `const char*`.

Comment: And `0L`? Use nullptr

Comment: @deviantfan Or `NULL` or `0`, if you don't have C++11.  The `0L` is confusing.

Answer (score 3):

C++ allows the implicit casting of a `T*` to a `const T*` for any type `T` so in your case you can just pass the parameter to the function.

Also, if you own the `Fl_Widget` constructor, then you should change the default value for `label` from `0L` to `nullptr`, or `0` if using C++03 or earlier.

(To convert from `const T*` to `T*` requires a `const_cast` and *can* lead to undefined behaviour).

Comment: In more general terms `const` can always be implicitly added, but not removed without `const_cast`, which should basically never be used.

Answer (score 0):

If your ctor currently looks like this, where `foo` is your class:

```
foo::foo() : FL_Widget(13, 13, 13, 13, Tmp){
    char Tmp[255]{"blah blah blah"};
}
```

That's not legal. You cannot pass a parameter to a parent ctor that happens in your class's ctor, this is because the parent ctor happens before your class ctor is called.

You could instead do this: `foo::foo() : FL_Widget(13, 13, 13, 13, "blah blah blah"){}`